# Function 'class' in Unity/C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity. My question isa, is it possible to create function files, without constructor and other stuff? In flash actionscript 3 it's look like this:

```
package util
{
    public function getRandomNumber(minQ:Number = 0, maxQ:Number = Number.MAX_VALUE):Number 
    {
        return minQ + Math.random() * (maxQ - minQ);
    }   
}
```

Is it possible to do somthing similar like this?

Comment: to declare a function you need at least namespace and class. you don't have to define constructors

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why do you want to this? What do you not like about classes?

Comment: whats wrong with Random.range that comes with unity

Comment: You can use a static class with static functions for something like hat.

Comment: Sweeper: I'm trying to port all of my code from flash to c#, Actionscript based on ECMA-262 like javascript. There are possible way to create functions without 'body', like getTimer(), where you don't have to create instance, just call it, and return the values, or do something.

Comment: #BugFinder: It's just an example. The question is: is it possible to create function (not class), like getTimer() or not.

Comment: #timur: Can you explain this? I mean can you write or link an example?

Comment: OT when you translate this method into .Net, don't create a Random instance inside the method - that may lead to identical "random" values if called often. IIRC Unity has its own random generator

Comment: FYI @AndrásNagy, to notify someone in a comment, use "@", not "#" (max 1 per comment)

Comment: @Hans Ke Ke ing: thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 7):

No, it is impossible in C#. I suggest you learn about [Extension Methods](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Extension_methods) and [Partial classes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Partial_classes).

You can use static classes and [singletons](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Science_Design_Patterns/Singleton) as well, but try to avoid the temptation to access it from every part of your project - it will be difficult to modify and refactor it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can do it in other way, I was just curious is it possible or not, and not found examples for that. Now I know the reason.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a global function, but you can create a static method in a static class:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public static class Util
   {
      public static double GetRandomNumber(..) { ... }
   }
}
```

and use it like

```
var myNumber = Util.GetRandomNumber(...);
```

The important part here is that the *method* is `static`, which means that you don't need an instance of the class to call it. The static *class* means that it is impossible to create an instance of that class.